# How to check if the user logged in or out with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook plugins:
how to check if the user logged in with php if the user logged in with javascript SDK?
and why i do need appId if i use login plugin for m site?

Comment: 1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/, 2. because an app _is_ what the logs into to.

Comment: Basically speaking, yes. Apps are tied to single domains (or subdomains thereof), to prevent that someone could use the same app all over the web and thereby gather data about a user’s web use easily.

Comment: And what would they use it for? And _where_ would they use it …? (As I already said, for logging in, apps are tied to a specific domain.)